# Why is this turning to 2d array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have some mock question of object here (don't mind the question and choices they're gibberish)

```
const questions = {
  iq_test: {
    questions: [
    {
      question: 'Find the difference', 
      choices: ['a1', 'a2', 'a1', 'a3'], 
      correct: 0
    }, 
    {
      question: 'What is the next sequence', 
      choices: ['2', '5', '56', '64'],
      correct: 3
    }, 
    { question: 'What should be the next letter', 
      choices: ['c', 'z', 'e', 'f'],
      correct: 3
    }]
  },
 memory_test: {
   ...omitted
 }
}
```

Now i want the `iq_test`

```
let retQuestions = Object.values(questions.iq_test).map(item => {
      console.log(item);
      return item;
})
```

The console.log inside the map gives me this format

```
    [ { question: 'Find the difference',
    choices: [ 'a1', 'a2', 'a1', 'a3' ],
    correct: 0 },
  { question: 'What is the next sequence',
    choices: [ '2', '5', '56', '64' ],
    correct: 3 },
  { question: 'What should be the next letter',
    choices: [ 'c', 'z', 'e', 'f' ],
    correct: 3 } ]
```

But when i console.log the retQuestions which should hold the return value i get different format

console.log(retQuestions) as you can see below it turn into 2d array

```
[ [ { question: 'Find the difference', choices: [Array], correct: 0 },
    { question: 'What is the next sequence',
      choices: [Array],
      correct: 3 },
    { question: 'What should be the next letter',
      choices: [Array],
      correct: 3 } ] ]
```

I want to map again this time to retQuestions to get each question but i can't since the format is changing..

Comment: since you use `map` you need `retQuestions.forEach(x=>console.log(x))`

Comment: @appleapple OP just do not need to `console.log` the value :)

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal :)

Answer (score 0):

`Object.values` gives back an array of all values in that object. Since `questions.iq_test` is itself an object with only one key value pair, you will get back a 2d array in this case. Try logging that once.

For what you're trying to achieve, you should instead call map on the object's value directly. For example,

```
let retQuestions = questions.iq_test.questions.map(item => {
      console.log(item);
      return item;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> The Object.values() method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable property values, in the same order as that provided by a for...in loop (the difference being that a for-in loop enumerates properties in the prototype chain as well).

So In your case you need to execute `map` on `questions.iq_test.questions` and since you are simply returning the `item`, you can avoid the `return` keyword.

```js
const questions = {
  iq_test: {
    questions: [
    {
      question: 'Find the difference', 
      choices: ['a1', 'a2', 'a1', 'a3'], 
      correct: 0
    }, 
    {
      question: 'What is the next sequence', 
      choices: ['2', '5', '56', '64'],
      correct: 3
    }, 
    { question: 'What should be the next letter', 
      choices: ['c', 'z', 'e', 'f'],
      correct: 3
    }]
  },
 memory_test: {
 }
}

let retQuestions = questions.iq_test.questions.map(item => item);
console.log(retQuestions);
```